# How can I make use of customized icons in PrimeFaces?

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, icons, styling

PrimeFaces provides a lot of icons from jQuery themeroller. They're useful but I need to have some customized icons for my app. Suppose I have a `<p:commandButton>`:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-check" />
```

Since my CSS knowledge is very limited, I'd be very grateful if you could show me how I can put some customized icon into the label of the above button.

Best regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define your own css class:

```
.img-button-help { background-image: url('../images/help.png') !important; }
```

and then use this class in your `p:commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton icon="img-button-help" />
```

Answer (score 1):

to create your own (user defined/customized) ui-icon in jsf primefaces follow these steps:

1. My image name is "pencilfour.png", put it inside resources folder in webapp.
2. Define your own icon with a new name
   inside "style" tag in your xhtml page:

   > .uipencil-icon {
   >
   > ```
   > width: 16px; 
   >
   >     height: 16px;
   >
   >     align:up;
   >
   >     background-image: url(#{resource['img:pencilfour.png']})!important ; 
   > }
   > ```

you can modify with and height as per your requirement.

3. Then you can use the defined icon with the command button

> ```
> <p:commandButton 
>
> icon="uipencil-icon"
>
>     style="   vertical-align:middle;
>
>     margin-right:10px;
>
>   height:19px;
>
>   width:19px;"
>
>   </p:commandButton>
> ```

this will work, the only thing to take care about is providing the correct `url: url(#{resource['img:pencilfour.png']})!important ;`
the syntax for url is imp to fetch the image on the command button :)

Comment: How is this, other then the 'url format' different from the upvoted and accepted answer?