# how to create custom icons in primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

i want to create an new icon to use in my `p:commandButton` but i failed i used this methode

> [PrimeFaces: how can I make use of customized icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120311/primefaces-how-can-i-make-use-of-customized-icons)

but didnt work for me . i will show you my code :

CSS CODE :

```
.img-button-help { background-image: url('img/mag.ico') !important; }
```

jsf CODE :

```
<p:commandButton icon="img-button-help" value="test" />
```

result :
[image]  new result ->[image]

how to use customed icons in Primefaces ??

Comment: Looks like there's no image found, thus there's no icon to display. Using Chrome or Firefox with Firebug installed, press F12 and see if you can access to this icon in the Resource section.

Comment: i think the image is founded but not showen or adapted for p:commandbutton

Comment: Are you sure the image is found? Have you verified if can be accessed from your site? One way to verify it is using the approach I explained in my comment above. Here's the documentation for Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/resources

Comment: i didnt find it in image folder in googlebug but when i write the url that i know in google i can see the image.

Comment: Then the problem is that the image isn't found (as I guessed). It would be better if you place all your resources inside a `resources` folder as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415/1065197

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try to add the `background-position` to your css because primefaces images are based on sprites and what `.img-button-help` does is set a positon. Try this:

```
.img-button-help { 
   background-image: url('img/mag.ico') !important;  
   background-position: center !important;
}
```

Comment: didnt work too i have an empty place like the image that i posted.

Comment: try to set the position in px

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution to this problem inspriring by Danko i created a small icon and i put it as background in the left

```
<p:commandButton value="test" style=" padding-left: 15px;background-image: url('img/mag.ico') !important;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: left;" />
```

now i have it as an icon with using an the icon of primefaces .

Comment: Better to go with css styles