# How to show icon at the right side of a p:menuitem value

Tags: primefaces

How to show some icon next to text in the PrimeFaces

I am using `p:submenu` like the following

```html
<p:submenu id="test" label="Manu Name"> 
    <p:menuitem id="menu1" value="Menu1 #{someController.showRedAlert ? 'redAlert' : ''}" outcome="myOutCome" ></p:menuitem>
</p:submenu>
```

I would like to show some icon next to Menu1 like the following image, I tried to set `icon` and `iconPos="right"` but i could not get it working the way i wanted.

Please refer the image
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `iconPos` is present in the tag definition for `menuitem` but it doesn't appear to be used at all in the underlying code. Instead, you can add the content you want between the opening and closing `menuitem` tags. For example:

```html
<p:menuitem action="nextScreen">Send
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"/>
</p:menuitem>
```

[image]

To make the text align, add a dummy or white icon to the `menuitem`. Here I used angle-bracket to illustrate.

```html
<p:menuitem action="nextScreen" icon="pi pi-angle-right">Send
    <i class="pi pi-envelope"/>
</p:menuitem>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work instead: `<p:menuitem id="crmClientTakeAction" outcome="takeActionHome" > My Take Actions <f:param name="paramName" value="parmVal" /> <i class="#{someController.valueExist ? 'fa fa-envelope' : ''}"/> </p:menuitem>` ?

Comment: The text for the menu item must be between the menuitem tags for this to work, not in a value attribute. If only the icon is not working, make sure the FontAwesome context parameter is set in web.xml, or switch to prime icons (pi pi-envelope) or [define a new CSS class for the icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120311/how-can-i-make-use-of-customized-icons-in-primefaces). Which version of PF are you using?